# grouping by 24 hours from date time

Tags: google-bigquery

I need count of events by every hour even if in some hour there is no events.
How can I include those hours in a group by without creating a temp table? I checked all similar posts but couldn't find answer. 
Lets say

```
select extract(hour from time(date_time)) as Hour, count(*)
from table_A
group by hour
order by hour
```

this get me count only for hours where there is event.
I am using Bigquery

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're using BigQuery, don't tag 3 other RDBMS please. It'll actually confuse the volunteers you're asking for help from more, and you're therefore less likely to get an answer. Every RDBMS has different syntax and if we don't specifically know which you're using then we can't actually provide a correct solution. (Plus many of us aren't fluent in every version of SQL, and instead maybe only 1 or 2. If you tag an RDBMS we don't know then we'll likely ignore the question, as we think we won't be able to help with the {MySQL/SQL Server/etc} side of things.)

Comment: Okay, thanks I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `generate_array()` and `unnest()` to generate the hours:

```
select h, count(a.date_time)
from unnest(generate_array(0, 23)) h left join
     table_A a
     on extract(hour from time(a.date_time)) = h
group by h
order by h;
```

This is slightly more complicated than the `generate_series()` supported by Postgres databases, but it does the job in a simple fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with SQL. For an SQL solution, I'd generate 24 hours on the fly and cross join to that. For ex:

```
;WITH twenty_four_hour_range AS 
(
SELECT
       1 AS _hour
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
       1 + _hour
      FROM    twenty_four_hour_range
      WHERE 1 + _hour <=24
)
select _hour, COUNT(*)
from table_A CROSS JOIN 
twenty_four_hour_range
group by twenty_four_hour_range._hour
order by 1
```